# PHP how to find the duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I am using php and I want to display list of records from database.
Say for example, the following is the table structure

```
sno val1 val2 val3  amt
1    2c   3e   I    500
2    2b   i7   I    1500
3    2w   u9   I    0
4    18   e3   I    50
5    2c   3e   S    70
```

Now I want to display records like below,

```
sno val1  val2  value
1    2c    3e    1
2    2b    i7    1
3    2w    u9    1
4    18    e3    1
5    2c    3e    0 //because already listed
```

I'm using normal while loop to show this structure, but I don't know weather the value is already listed or not..

Can anyone help

Comment: what does the value zero mean?

Comment: Add each value to an array and before that check if it already exists?

Comment: In result, `value` column represents just like the count of this `val1 & val2` field values

Comment: would `array_merge` do this? When array1 and array2 are merged, it will skip a duplicate. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: I want to show all records( with duplicates), the only thing if already listed means i want to show 0

Comment: Are `val3` and `amt` relevant to the present problem?

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

```
$listed = array();
while() // your loop
{
    if(in_array($uniq_id_of_your_item, $listed)) {
         continue;
    }
    $listed[] = $uniq_id_of_your_item;

    // rest of your code
}
```

Second solution (better): you can limit that in SQL query

Comment: Data will come from db and minimum 100 and maximum 10000 records.. Then how will i achieve this with array and in_array?

Comment: With select, count, join and group by :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT a.sno, a.val1, a.val2,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END value
FROM table_name a
JOIN table_name b 
ON a.val1 = b.val1 
   AND a.val2 = b.val2 
   AND a.sno >= b.sno
GROUP BY a.sno
```